# AWS DynamoDB LoadTable Fatal Error in Android?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have 2 tables that I want to use in my Android application from DynamoDB, I made this DynamoHelper class:

```
public class DynamoHelper {
    private Context context;
    private CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
    private AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDBClient;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static volatile DynamoHelper INSTANCE = null;

    public static synchronized DynamoHelper getINSTANCE(Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            INSTANCE = new DynamoHelper(context);
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private DynamoHelper(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(this.context, "us-east-1:---", Regions.US_EAST_1);
        dynamoDBClient = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentialsProvider);
        dynamoDBClient.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1));
    }

    public CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider getCredentialsProvider() {
        return credentialsProvider;
    }

    public AmazonDynamoDBClient getDynamoDBClient() {
        return dynamoDBClient;
    }
}
```

And this DynamoTable class:

```
public abstract class DynamoTable {
    private final Context context;
    private String tableName;
    public Table table;

    DynamoTable(String tableName, Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.tableName = tableName;
        DynamoHelper dynamoHelper = DynamoHelper.getINSTANCE(context);

        table = Table.loadTable(dynamoHelper.getDynamoDBClient(), tableName);
    }

    public Document insertInTable(Document item) {
        PutItemOperationConfig putItemOperationConfig = new PutItemOperationConfig();
        putItemOperationConfig.withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD);

        return table.putItem(item, putItemOperationConfig);
    }

    public Document deleteFromTable(String id) {
        return table.deleteItem(new Primitive(id), new DeleteItemOperationConfig().withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD));
    }

    public List<Document> getAllFromTable(List<String> attributes) {
        ScanOperationConfig scanOperationConfig = new ScanOperationConfig();
        scanOperationConfig.withAttributesToGet(attributes);
        Search searchResult = table.scan(scanOperationConfig);
        return searchResult.getAllResults();
    }

    public abstract boolean updateInTable(Document item);

    public Table getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    public void setTable(Table table) {
        this.table = table;
    }
}
```

And this AddItemAsyncTask class:

```
public class AddItemTask extends AsyncTask<Document, Void, Void> {
    private DynamoTable dynamoTable;

    public AddItemTask(DynamoTable dynamoTable) {
        this.dynamoTable = dynamoTable;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Document... documents) {
        dynamoTable.insertInTable(documents[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Im trying to save some data by clicking a button that does this:

```
private void addUserToDB() {
        User user = new User(SignUpActivity.this, "Users", nameEdit.getText().toString(), phoneEdit.getText().toString(),
                birthdayEdit.getText().toString(), statusEdit.getText().toString(), getString(R.string.no_image_link), null);

        AddItemTask addItemTask = new AddItemTask(user);

        Document document = new Document();

        document.put("id", user.getPhone());
        document.put("name", user.getName());
        document.put("birthdate", user.getBirthdate());
        document.put("status", user.getStatus());
        document.put("picture", user.getPicture());

        addItemTask.execute(document);
    }
```

But every time I run, It gives me this error at the line in the DynamoTable class that says "Table.LoadTable" :

```
2020-05-22 21:08:39.627 22674-22674/com.example.homing E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.homing, PID: 22674
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5634)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:5629)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:117)
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:105)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1154)
        at com.android.okhttp.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:39)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:175)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:141)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:83)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:174)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:126)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:95)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:281)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:224)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:461)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:127)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:162)
        at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:75)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:371)
        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:566)
        at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:448)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:172)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.refresh(AWSEnhancedCognitoIdentityProvider.java:76)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.startSession(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:678)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:465)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:485)
        at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:77)
        at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:5157)
2020-05-22 21:08:39.627 22674-22674/com.example.homing E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.describeTable(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1526)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.document.Table.loadTableDescription(Table.java:124)
        at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.document.Table.loadTable(Table.java:110)
        at com.example.homing.models.classes.DynamoTable.<init>(DynamoTable.java:31)
        at com.example.homing.models.classes.User.<init>(User.java:22)
        at com.example.homing.views.activities.SignUpActivity.addUserToDB(SignUpActivity.java:130)
        at com.example.homing.views.activities.SignUpActivity.signUp(SignUpActivity.java:97)
            ... 13 more
```

I already have the internet accesses in the manifest and Im linking to an identity pool where i added permissions for dynamoDB..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had AsyncTask classes for the insert but I loaded the table in the main thread.

I solved this by making another AsyncTask to load the table so it runs on a different thread instead of the main UI one.